# Laravel Deny Direct Access to Files Via URL, but allow download after logged in?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3, apache and php 5.6, **I need to deny direct access to files via url, but i need to download those files after the user Logged in via url or general php request to download a file**, i ain't using Auth, i am using my own procedure for logging in. First is it possible to do so?
  I have kept my files in

> project/public/uploads/{clientid}/sample.txt

I know its a bad practice to store files in public folder instead of storing it in storage folder, but the project was developed initially in such a way and we need to overcome the direct access to files, is there anyway to do it, i have tried some by editing my .htaccess inside the public folder,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1    
<Files /../index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<FilesMatch ".*\.(css|js)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Anyhow this only allow css and js files inside public folder, but deny all other files that is kept inside the public folder via url and php general post download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has better solution 
you save your files to storage
and You can do it for download

```
return response()->download($file);
```

that your file is absolute pass of file in storage 
you can manage them who can download and who cant and its secure

So after you do it you create one route like this:

```
Route::get('download/{file}',function($file){
return response()->download(storage_path($file));
});
```

you can do anything with route like add middleware for auth user or ....

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, if we store file in storage will it be accessible via URL?

Comment: @shariff854 but its still accessible by full path like ..storage/app/public/download/sample.txt, we cant access only through the defined routes.

Comment: except public folder all other folders is not accessabile in the web and with url . they protected by htaccess